# Sparse generalized symmetric eigensystem solver

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigensystem, software-recommendation

Can anyone recommend a good software for solving generalized symmetric eigenvalue problems of the form,
$$
A x = \lambda B x
$$
where $A,B$ are symmetric and sparse, and $B$ is positive definite?

I have only 1 machine so I would prefer something based on OpenMP rather than MPI if possible.

Comment: Do you have any programming language constraint?

Comment: ARPACK is a good choice. So is SLEPc.

Comment: +1 SLEPc for this problem